# How would I get custom-colored equation numbers as simply as possible?

Tags: equations, numbering, color

In a continuation of efforts to create a complete SAE technical paper class file, I need a little help finding the easiest way to create colored equation numbers. In my class file, I already define caption colors via the following:

```
\Requirepackage{color}
\definecolor{SAEblue}{rgb}{0, .62, .91}
\renewcommand\captionfont{\color{SAEblue}\small}
```

Similarly, in my mind, there must be a simple command I could alter, like:

```
\renewcommand\eqnumfont{color{SAEblue}}
```

However, I haven't found it on the forum. There are some more complicated examples, and also examples that define a `\colorlabel` property within `equation` or `align` environments, but I would like to define something within my class files that globally makes all equation labels my custom color. I'm not sure what package sets the color of equation numbers (by default).

Comment: We need a complete minimal example as we don't know what is formatting your equation numbers by default in your class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can change `\@eqnnum` but whether this is what you want is impossible to say without more details about your class code and your desired results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@eqnnum}{\normalcolor}{\color{magenta}}{\typeout{eqnnum patch: OK!}}{\typeout{eqnnum patch: Oh, dear!}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  1 + 2 = 3\label{eq:siml}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: magenta equation numbering]

Comment: This is great. I just need to figure out what package is blocking me from being able to use this in my class file. It works as a MWE but not in my test document.

Comment: Ok, I determined this doesn't work because of the mhchem package I am using for making pretty looking chemical formulas in my document. Now to figure out why...

Comment: Ok I'm going to formulate this into a new question with a very simple MWE as I think that would be the appropriate way forward.

Comment: Continuing this issue in the following thread to find a solution that is compatible with amsmath. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292583/mhchem-amsmath-seems-to-change-the-eqnnum-macro-so-i-cant-change-equation-numb

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `\newtagform` and `\usetagform`commands, defined by `mathtools`, and have different styles for tags within the same document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\newtagform{blue}{\color{RoyalBlue3}(}{)}
\newtagform{redandblue}[\textcolor{RoyalBlue3}]{\color{red}(}{)}
\begin{document}
\usetagform{blue}
\begin{equation}
\label{blueeq}
  a =b + d
\end{equation}
From \eqref{blueeq} we deduce: 
\usetagform{redandblue}
\begin{equation}
\label{RandB}
c = d \times e
\end{equation}
But \eqref{RandB} does not imply \usetagform{blue}\eqref{blueeq}.

\usetagform{default} 
\begin{equation}
  f =g + h
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the equation number coloured then redefine `\theequation`:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{SAEblue}{rgb}{0, .62, .91}
\renewcommand\theequation{{\color{SAEblue}\arabic{equation}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2+\varepsilon
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you want the brackets coloured as well then @cfr has the answer:)