# mhchem/amsmath seems to change the @eqnnum macro so I can't change equation number colors globally. How would I fix this issue?

Tags: amsmath, mhchem

Thanks to cfr [How would I get custom-colored equation numbers as simply as possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292473/how-would-i-get-custom-colored-equation-numbers-as-simply-as-possible/292477#292477) for providing a hint on how to do this without the mhchem/amsmath packages installed. To see what I mean, Here is a MWE. If I comment out the `\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}` line, I get the desired result. It seems that `mhchem` must redefine the `\@eqnnum` macro somehow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\definecolor{SAEblue}{rgb}{0, .62, .91}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@eqnnum}{\normalcolor}{\color{SAEblue}}{\typeout{eqnnum patch: OK!}}{\typeout{eqnnum patch: Oh, dear!}}
\begin{document}    
\begin{equation}
  1 + 2 = 3\label{eq:siml}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I searched through `mhchem.sty`, `mhchem.tex`, `hpstatement.sty`, and `rsphrase.sty`. It's all a little above my head, but I didn't see anything obvious that would cause this issue. My next step was to see what packages were required by `mhchem`, and I came up with the following list:

```
expl3, l3keys2e, l3regex, calc[1998/07/07], amsmath, chemgreek[2015/04/09], graphics, ifthen, textcomp, babel, twoopt
```

None of these cause problems except for `amsmath`. The following MWE works fine until you uncomment the `amsmath` line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\usepackage{calc}[1998/07/07]
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemgreek}[2015/04/09]
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{twoopt}
%\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\definecolor{SAEblue}{rgb}{0, .62, .91}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@eqnnum}{\normalcolor}{\color{SAEblue}}{\typeout{eqnnum patch: OK!}}{\typeout{eqnnum patch: Oh, dear!}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  1 + 2 = 3\label{eq:siml}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Uncommenting `amsmath` will make the color go back to black (but there is no error).

In the `amsmath.ins`, I see the following:

```
\iftagsleft@
  \def\@eqnnum{\hbox to1sp{}\rlap{\normalfont\normalcolor
    \hskip -\displaywidth\tagform@\theequation}}
\else
  \def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont\normalcolor \tagform@\theequation}}
\fi
```

I would think that by me redefining the `\@eqnnum` through the patch, this would not make a difference, but I honestly have only a small glimpse of how all this stuff really works.

At this point, I am seeking the guidance of more experience community members to get this to work with the `amsmath`/`mhchem` packages in use.

Comment: not an expert on patching, but it's possible that the multiple definition of `\@eqnnum` in `amsmath` is relevant.  your tags are probably on the right, and if only the first instance of `\@eqnnum` + `\normalcolor` is patched by your code, the second one would remain in the original form.  you don't say whether this just doesn't work, leaving the numbers black, or whether it results in an error.  that is necessary information.

Comment: `mhchem` loads `amsmath`, so the real 'villain' is `amsmath` here, but I could not figure out the cause for this

Comment: @barbarabeeton, there is no error, it just leaves the numbers black if amsmath is loaded.

Comment: I also tried just repeating the patch multple times... this has no effect.

Comment: you might try, rather than patching, just redefining `\@eqnnum`, replacing `\normalcolor` by the color you want.  be sure to wrap it between `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong patch, because, when `amsmath` is loaded, the printing of the equation number is not delegated to `\@eqnnum` any more or, at least, it is in a different way. See, for example, [adjust alignment of equation numbers with leqno](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261642/adjust-alignment-of-equation-numbers-with-leqno)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\definecolor{SAEblue}{rgb}{0, .62, .91}

\makeatletter
% detach \eqref and \tag making
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\eqreftagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\let\eqreftagform@\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{\color{SAEblue}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

In equation~\eqref{eq:siml} we state a truth.
\begin{equation}
  1 + 2 = 3\label{eq:siml}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that also `\eqref` prints the equation number in blue, comment out the two lines before `\def\@tagform@`.

Comment: This worked perfectly in my class file, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have a 'hacky' solution:

`mhchem` loads `amsmath`, so omitting `amsmath` will cause the wrong colour setting anyway if `mhchem` is included.

The culprit is `\gdef\df@tag{\tagform@\theequation}` in `\endmathdisplay@`, in my point of view, omitting the colour change done by `\@eqnnum`. I've used another patch and introduced a general `\mathtagcolor`, that's defined to be the `SAEblue` colour here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\usepackage{calc}[1998/07/07]

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemgreek}[2015/04/09]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{twoopt}

\newcommand{\mathtagcolor}{\normalcolor}

\definecolor{SAEblue}{rgb}{0, .62, .91}


\renewcommand{\mathtagcolor}{SAEblue}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 

\makeatletter
  \xpatchcmd{\@eqnnum}{\normalcolor}{\color{\mathtagcolor}}{\typeout{eqnnumpatch: OK!}}{\typeout{eqnnum patch: Oh, dear!}}
    \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
  \xpatchcmd{\endmathdisplay@a}{%
    \tagform@\theequation
  }{%
    \color{\mathtagcolor}\tagform@\theequation
  }{\typeout{patching \protect\endmathdisplay@a\ succeeded}}{\typeout{patching \protect\endmathdisplay@a\ failed}}
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  1 + 2 = 3\label{eq:siml}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]