# How to colour only equation or figure number in \crefrange

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, color, cleveref

I am using cleveref to reference ranges of figures and equations. I can give different colour using `\textcolor{}`, but i need to color only equations number, not text. How can I do that?

```
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{align}
C_{11}^{0} &= C_{33}^{0} = \lambda + 2\mu                   \label{eq:2} \\
C_{13}^{0} &= \lambda                                                      \label{eq:3} \\
C_{44}^{0} &= C_{66}^{0} = \mu                                      \label{eq:4} 
\end{align}
```

This is what i use to color all text.

```
\textcolor{violet}{\crefrange{eq:2}{eq:4}}.
```

How to colour only equation number?
e.g.

```
\crefrange \textcolor{violet}{eq:2} \textcolor{violet}{eq:4}}.
```

Comment: What do you mean with "equation number"? Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292473/how-would-i-get-custom-colored-equation-numbers-as-simply-as-possible

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Should all equation numbers be colored in violet whenever they occur in a cross-reference? Or is this the case only if the equation numbers occur in the argument of `\crefrange`? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help. Yes I need all EQUATIONS and FIGURES number colored in violet whenever they occur in a cross-reference by \crefrange or ~\ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve your formatting objective by issuing suitable `\creflabelformat` instructions.

Observe that the following solution works with the user-level macros of the `cleveref` package, such as `\cref`, `\labelcref`, and `\crefrange`. It does not work with `\ref`; I suspect that modifying the TeX/Latex built-in macro `\ref`, just to make it render its output in color, might be a poor idea.

In the following solutions, I use red and blue since violet may not show up very clearly on some screens.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for \textcolor macro

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % per the OP's example
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}#3}
\creflabelformat{figure}{#2(\textcolor{blue}{#1})#3}

\begin{document}
\labelcref{eq:2}; \cref{eq:3}; \crefrange{eq:2}{eq:4}

\labelcref{fig:a}; \cref{fig:c}; \crefrange{fig:a}{fig:c}

% Minimalist code to create meaningful \label instructions:
\stepcounter{equation}
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{eq:2} 
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{eq:3} 
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{eq:4}
\refstepcounter{figure} \label{fig:a}
\refstepcounter{figure} \label{fig:b}
\refstepcounter{figure} \label{fig:c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly